# iPhone Get Index of an array from Value in a Key

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have the next `NSMutableArray`:

```
Product[0] {
    name => val1, 
    Price => pricevalue 1
}

Product[1] {
    name => val2, 
    Price => pricevalue2
}
```

I want to search for: `name` = `val2` and return the index of product, so 1.

Comment: There are ways to do it that require fewer lines of code, but no way more efficient than the straight-forward loop which you can easily code yourself.  There's no need to look for "clever" ways to do something if you can do it yourself, reasonably efficiently, with simple, straight-forward loops and if statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
__block NSUInteger index = NSUIntegerMax;

[products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^ (Product* product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop) {
    if([product.name isEqualToString:@"val2"])
    {
        index = idx;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

**Edit:** Ravindra's solution is more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
NSIndexSet *indices = [array 
                       indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                       return [[obj objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"val2"];
}];
```

Happy coding.........